Which calling convention to use for Visual C++ to call a DLL function written in Delphi?
I am using Delphi XE3 write a function, as follows:
function CheckLicense(const lpszAppName: PChar): Integer; stdcall;
begin
...
end;

exports
   CheckLicense;

Then should I use CALLBACK in Visual C++ to call it:
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  /* __cplusplus */

    typedef INT (CALLBACK* CHECKLICENSEPROC)(LPCTSTR lpszAppName);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Or use __stdcall instead?
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  /* __cplusplus */

    typedef INT (__stdcall* CHECKLICENSEPROC)(LPCTSTR lpszAppName);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Is that correct?

CALLBACK is just an alias for __stdcall. Same with WINAPI, too. But, since your exported function is not a callback function, from a semantic perspective I would not suggest usingCALLBACK, use WINAPI or __stdcall directly. It doesn't really matter.
Also, LPCTSTR is the wrong type to use for the 1st parameter. That type switches between const char* and const wchar_t* depending on project settings, but PChar in Delphi 2009 and later is strictly wchar_t* only, so use LPCWSTR (aka const wchar_t*) instead.
